# Bitcoin Widget To Display Exchange Rate On Top Menu

Tags: plugins, bitcoin

Just wondering if anyone knows if there's a widget/app to display Bitcoin exchange rate on the top menu on Ubuntu. I would love it even though it's easy to check the rate on the web. When I search on the Ubuntu Software Center and Google I can't even  find a desktop widget or even a program. Thanks. 
mMm

Answer (score 3):

I have the answer for you. 
I am using **coinprice-indicator**.

You can dowload it from github here [coinprice-indicator](https://github.com/nilgradisnik/coinprice-indicator)

After you have download and installed it, please follow the instructions in this [**question**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588217/how-can-i-make-coinprice-indicator-open-from-startup).

After all you will have an indicator applet who shows the BTC price.